# How to unit test a react event handler that contains history.push using Jest and Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, html5-history

Given a simple component:

```
export default class SearchForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { query: '' }
  }
  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    history.push(`/results/${this.state.query}`, { query: this.state.query })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.query}
          onChange={event => this.setState({ query: event.target.value })}
        />
        <button>Search</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

And the test:

```
describe('SearchForm Component', () => {
  it('should navigate to results/query when submitted', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<SearchForm />)
    ...?
  })
})
```

How do you verify that form submission is taking the user to the next page with the correct query value?

I've tried simply mocking the onSubmit handler and at least confirming that it's been called, but this results in a security error due to `history.push`.

```
const wrapper = shallow(<SearchForm />)
const mockedEvent = { target: {}, preventDefault: () => {} }
const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'onSubmit')
wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', mockedEvent)
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's actually simple, you can pass in any props to the component when shallow rendering it inside the test, like that:
`const wrapper = shallow(<SearchForm history={historyMock} />)`

By the way, inside `onSubmit`, you should call like `this.props.history.push(...)`.

Now, to create a mock (more info in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html)), you can write like this in the test:
`const historyMock = { push: jest.fn() };`

Keep in mind that you are actually mocking only the `push` method of the `history` object, if you use more methods inside the component and want to test them, you should create a mock to each one tested.

And then, you need to assert that the `push` mock was called correctly. To do that, you write the assertion necessary:
`expect(historyMock.push.mock.calls[0]).toEqual([ (url string), (state object) ]);`
Use the needed `(url string)` and `(state object)` to be asserted.

Comment: To add to the answer, keep in mind that you can pass any parameter that you want when shallow rendering a component, not just mocks.

Comment: this requires adding additional props and changing our target component though, right?

Comment: @DamianGreen not really, the objective in the end is asserting that the `push` function from the object `history` is called correctly, and `history` is passed as props.