# Testing React Router redirection with async componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-router, enzyme

*tl/dr: How do I wait for an async `componentDidMount`, simulate a React Router redirect and test the resulting page?*

I have a React component with a `componentDidMount` which asynchronously requests data from an API then sets state.

In my Enzyme/Mocha tests, I can wait for `componentDidMount` like this:

```
  it('should show an input with quantity 0 by default', async () => {
    const component = shallow(<ShowPage />);
    await component.instance().componentDidMount();
    component.update();
    expect(component.find('h1').text()).to.eq('Show page');
  });
```

This is fine, but I also want to test a button click which redirects the user to another page. This uses:

```
this.props.history.push('/redirect-to')
```

The `history` prop is not available unless I wrap the component in a `MemoryRouter`:

```
const component = mount(<MemoryRouter><ShowPage /></MemoryRouter>);
```

But now I can't access the `ShowPage` component's `componentDidMount` because:

```
await component.find('BurgerShow').instance().componentDidMount();
```

gets me:

```
instance() can only be called on the root
```

I feel like I'm making very heavy weather of this. What is the correct approach here?

Comment: I found [some advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50684599/2071807) suggesting mocking the `history.push`. Is this the right way to proceed?