# How to properly test history.replace and history.push in React apps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

When i try to test replace or push i either get empthy object that represents history or when i use mock it is never being called.
Currently i get this :   Cannot spy the replace property because it is not a function; undefined given instead 
or when i use mock it dosnt get called.

```html
const submitHandler = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/auth/signup'
    const signupData = {
      email,
      password,
      matchPassword,
      username
    }
    const responseData = await postData(apiUrl,signupData,'')
    if (responseData === undefined) {
      toggleValidationErrors([
        {
          param: 'server-error',
          msg: `Server isn't availdable.Please try again later!`
        }
      ]);
    } else if (responseData.validationErrors) {
      toggleValidationErrors(responseData.validationErrors);
    } else {
      history.replace(`/login`);
    }
  };

import React from 'react'

import {render,fireEvent, getByValue,waitForElement} from 'react-testing-library'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignupForm from './SignupForm'
describe('<SignupForm />',() => {
    const username = "testUser";
    const email = "testEmail@email.com";
    const password = 'testpass1012'
    const matchPassword = 'testpass1012'
    const history = { replace: jest.fn() };
    const { container, getByPlaceholderText, getByValue,getByText } = render (<SignupForm />,{wrapper:BrowserRouter})
    beforeEach(() => {    

        const submitButton = getByText('SIGN UP')
        fireEvent.click(submitButton)
    })
   
      it('should call history.replace',() => {
          
        const replaceSpy = jest.spyOn(history, 'replace');

          expect(replaceSpy).toBeCalled()
          replaceSpy.mockRestore()
      })
})
```

Comment: You could use ***Jest*** to test history push. https://jestjs.io/

Comment: Im using jest.The test is at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682726/how-to-unit-test-a-react-event-handler-that-contains-history-push-using-jest-and

Comment: I did but i couldn't replicate it using react-testing-library

Answer (score 1):

The history spy you created would have to get passed into the component you are testing in order for it to get called. The history spy is not being passed in, which is why you are getting undefined.

If your `<SignupForm />` component is receiving the history prop, then simply pass in the history spy you created in your test file and it should work.

Another approach would be to create a separate file, say in a util folder and import

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
```

You have access to this when you install react-router.
Then, export the following:

```
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

This creates a history object exactly like you get from the react-router history object. From here you could then import the `createBrowserHistory` object into your test file and make assertions about the history.

Comment: Both ways dont seem to work.Im getting  : Cannot spy the replace property because it is not a function; undefined give
n instead. Or :  Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.